# JPA eclipselink OID Large Object PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, jpa, netbeans, primefaces, eclipselink

I am new to JPA, I have a problem with fields PostgreSQL oid types (field foto), I'm trying to store an image captured from the interface through a p:fileupload of Primefaces  and have not succeeded. The IDE I've mapped the picture field data type BigInteger.
They tried the following:

- I wanted to convert a BigInteger FileUploadEvent byte and a Bug me
  stumped.
- Thinking that the IDE was incorrectly mapped OID change the data type
  to byte [] and became the bytes returned the FileUploadEvent me and I
  gave the error.

  **[EL Warning]: 01/12/2013 16:54:51.2 - ServerSession (1488263888) - Exception [EclipseLink-3002] (Eclipse Persistence Services -
  2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions . ConversionException
  Exception Description: The object [94,750], of class [class java.lang.Long], from mapping [org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.DirectToFieldMapping [photo -> candidato.foto]] with descriptor [RelationalDescriptor (Entity.Candidato -> [DatabaseTable (candidate)])], could not be converted to [class [B].**

Add the annotation @ Lob for the two previous cases and did not work either, I do not know if I apply any prior conversion or something.

IDE: Netbeans 7.2

DBMS: PostgreSQL 9.0

Persistence Engine: EclipseLink 2.3.2

I hope I can help.

Table BD

```
CREATE TABLE candidato
    (
      idcandidato serial NOT NULL,
      idtipoidentificacion integer,
      numeroidentificacion character varying(100),
      nombres character varying(100),
      foto oid,
      n_foto character varying(50),
      CONSTRAINT candidato_pkey PRIMARY KEY (idcandidato),
    )
    WITH (
      OIDS=FALSE
    );
```

Entity Candidato with BigInteger (Netbeans generator)

```
@Column(name = "foto")
private BigInteger foto;

public BigInteger getFoto() {
    return foto;
}

public void setFoto(BigInteger foto) {
    this.foto = foto;
}
```

Entity Candidato with Change of Type (byte[])

```
@Column(name = "foto")
private byte[] foto;

public byte[] getFoto() {
    return foto;
}

public void setFoto(byte[] foto) {
    this.foto = foto;
}
```

Comment: Don't use `oid` for blobs. Use `bytea`.

Comment: a_horse_with_no_name, why not use oid for Blobs.? http://goo.gl/GQ81t

Comment: Because an OID is just a "pointer" and is very Postgres specific. Hardly any library (apart from the Postgres specific ones) handles them correctly. A `bytea` on the other hand behaves like the `BLOB` datatype in most (if not all) other DBMS, so generic libraries (such as an ORM) can cope with that much better. Plus there is no need for housekeeping with `bytea` (with oid you need to manually remove the file they point to). Unless you need to store files larger than 1GB or you always access only parts of the data, `bytea` is really the better choice.

Comment: If you have to put them in the database use bytea but you should seriously consider not putting them in the DB at all. Just store the filenames. While storing them in a bytea field in the table guarantees consistency (which can safe you a few headaches) it will make your database and sql dumps of your database huge. Also it very quickly becomes a bottleneck when serving the images on a website which means you will have to cache them as normal files on disk on the webserver anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to cause a bunch of confusion for hibernate users.  For most cases you want `byte[]` on the hybernate side and `bytea` on the PostgreSQL side.  `bytea` stands for "byte array" so the two are more or less identical.  Byteas have a lot less overhead than lobs, but you may want to use a `lob` (`blob` in hybernate, and `oid` in PostgreSQL) if you need a streaming interface including the ability to seek within a `lob`.  For example if you are storing streaming video and may want to start a new chunked request 25MB in, LOBs will come in handy.

Answer (score 0):

How does Postgres return the OID type?  You most likely need to use a Converter to convert between a Java type and the OID type.

See,
http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/a_converter.htm#CHDEHJEB